# Append strings of different length to array

Tags: python, arrays, unicode, append, typeerror

I try to append content from a list looking like this: ["a", "b", "cd"] to an array. It is possible to append "single" strings like "a" and "b" but how do I append the "cd" ?

```
from array import array


def function(a):
    our_array = array("u",[])
    our_array.insert(0,a)
    print(our_array)


#Working
function("a")

#Not working
function("cd")
```

Comment: You should tell us the desired result.

Comment: You selected your array to be of type 'u' and that means unicode *character*. Arrays are not meant to store things of varied length inside them (arrays are meant to store single type to use compact memory). Therefore python arrays don't have any way to store strings that are not single character. So the question is: why are you using arrays when it seems you want an arbitrary list?

Comment: What actually are you trying to do? what do you want to use this array for? Are you just trying to have a "mutable string"? There are much better approaches for that. Also: **what do you think the result should be**? Are you expecting the entire `'cd'` string to be a single element in the array? Or do you want `'c'` and `'d'` to be two separate elements?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Can you name a better approach?

Comment: @KellyBundy I was thinking in particular of using `io.StringIO`. At least that way, the data is conceptually text rather than some low-level buffer (the size of the elements is implementation-defined for `'u'`, and in some cases won't hold characters outside the BMP).

Answer (score 0):

`array("u",[])` means that the type of `our_array` elements is `wchar_t` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)). As the `"cd"` is not `wchar_t` you can't put it into this array. You can use `list` for that purpose. For example:

```
def function(a):
    our_list = []
    our_list.append(a)
    print(our_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `array` interface only allows adding a single element using `.append`, and the string `'ab'` is not a single element for an array of the `u` type.

Suppose we have an existing array

```
x = array('u', 'cd')
```

To prepend `'ab'`, simply make another array from that string, and then insert it by using slicing:

```
x[:0] = array('u', 'ab')
```

Or concatenate the arrays and assign back:

```
x = array('u', 'ab') + x
```

Or iterate over the string:

```
for position, c in enumerate('ab'):
    x.insert(position, c)
```

Note that each insertion changes the position where the next value should be inserted, so we need to count upwards with the index. `enumerate` is the natural tool for that.

Answer (score -1):

`"".join()` allows you to do exactly that.

I refactored the function like so:

```
def function(a):
    letters = []
    for letter in a:
        letters.append(letter)
    our_array = array("u","".join(letters))
    print(our_array)
```